# How to 'restrict owner' but allow 'admin' role in Feathers

Tags: authentication, permissions, hook, rbac, feathersjs

I use feathers-permissions and feathers-authentication-hooks to build an RBAC system, but still cannot make it yet. What I want is for example:

- allow users to view/update only their own account.
- allow admin to view/update any accounts.

```js
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [authenticate('jwt'), checkPermissions({roles: ['admin']})],
    get: [authenticate('jwt'), checkPermissions({roles: ['admin']}), hooks.restrictToOwner({ownerField: '_id'})],
    create: [hashPassword()],
    update: [hashPassword(), authenticate('jwt'), checkPermissions({roles: ['admin']}), hooks.restrictToOwner({ownerField: '_id'})],
    patch: [hashPassword(), authenticate('jwt'), checkPermissions({roles: ['admin']}), hooks.restrictToOwner({ownerField: '_id'})],
    remove: [authenticate('jwt'), checkPermissions({roles: ['admin']})]
  },
```

This way admin still cannot view/update other accounts.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the `feathers-permissions` -> [Conditionally restricting roles](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-permissions#conditionally-restricting-roles)

In addition, yes it is best to use existing hooks like the ones in `feathers-hooks-common`. But if it is not doable then you can always create your own hook that will suit your needs.